# Python building complex mypy types

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy

In a perfect world, I could just do this:

```
ScoreBaseType = Union[bool, int, float]
ScoreComplexType = Union[ScoreBaseType, Dict[str, ScoreBaseType]]
```

But, that says a ScoreComplexType is either a ScoreBaseType or a dictionary which allows multiple types of values... not what I want.

The following looks like it should work to me, but it doesn't:

```
ScoreBaseTypeList = [bool, int, float]
ScoreBaseType = Union[*ScoreBaseTypeList]  # pycharm says "can't use starred expression here"
ScoreDictType = reduce(lambda lhs,rhs: Union[lhs, rhs], map(lambda x: Dict[str, x], ScoreBaseTypeList))
ScoreComplexType = Union[ScoreBaseType, ScoreDictType]
```

Is there any way I can do something like the above without having to go through this tedium?

```
ScoreComplexType = Union[bool, int, float,
                     Dict[str, bool],
                     Dict[str, int],
                     Dict[str, float]]
```

**Edit**: More fleshed out desired usage example:

```
# these strings are completely arbitrary and determined at runtime. Used as keys in nested dictionaries.
CatalogStr = NewType('CatalogStr', str)
DatasetStr = NewType('DatasetStr', str)
ScoreTypeStr = NewType('ScoreTypeStr', str)

ScoreBaseType = Union[bool, int, float]
ScoreDictType = Dict[ScoreTypeStr, 'ScoreBaseTypeVar']
ScoreComplexType = Union['ScoreBaseTypeVar', ScoreDictType]

ScoreBaseTypeVar = TypeVar('ScoreBaseTypeVar', bound=ScoreBaseType)
ScoreComplexTypeVar = TypeVar('ScoreComplexTypeVar', bound=ScoreComplexType) # errors: "constraints cannot be parameterized by type variables"

class EvalBase(ABC, Generic[ScoreComplexTypeVar]):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.scores: Dict[CatalogStr,
                          Dict[DatasetStr,
                               ScoreComplexTypeVar]
                          ] = {}

class EvalExample(EvalBase[Dict[float]]): # can't do this either
    ...
```

**Edit 2:**
It occurs to me that I could simplify a LOT of my type hinting if I used tuples instead of nested dictionaries. This seems to maybe work? I've only tried it in the below toy example and haven't yet tried adapting all my code.

```
# These are used to make typing hints easier to understand
CatalogStr = NewType('CatalogStr', str)  # A str corresponding to the name of a catalog
DatasetStr = NewType('DatasetStr', str)  # A str corresponding to the name of a dataset
ScoreTypeStr = NewType('ScoreTypeStr', str)  # A str corresponding to the label for a ScoreType

ScoreBaseType = Union[bool, int, float]

SimpleScoreDictKey = Tuple[CatalogStr, DatasetStr]
ComplexScoreDictKey = Tuple[CatalogStr, DatasetStr, ScoreTypeStr]
ScoreKey = Union[SimpleScoreDictKey, ComplexScoreDictKey]
ScoreKeyTypeVar = TypeVar('ScoreKeyTypeVar', bound=ScoreKey)
ScoreDictType = Dict[ScoreKey, ScoreBaseType]

# These are used for Generics in classes
DatasetTypeVar = TypeVar('DatasetTypeVar', bound='Dataset')  # Must match a type inherited from Dataset
ScoreBaseTypeVar = TypeVar('ScoreBaseTypeVar', bound=ScoreBaseType)


class EvalBase(ABC, Generic[ScoreBaseTypeVar, ScoreKeyTypeVar]):
    def __init__(self):
        self.score: ScoreDictType = {}


class EvalExample(EvalBase[float, ComplexScoreDictKey]):
    ...
```

Although then what would the equivalent of this be? Seems like I might have to store a couple lists of keys in order to iterate?

```
for catalog_name in self.catalog_list:
    for dataset_name in self.scores[catalog_name]:
        for score in self.scores[catalog_name][dataset_name]:
```

Answer (score 1):

You may need to use TypeVars to express this, but without an example of how you intend to use it, it's hard to say.

An example of how this would be used for typing a return value dependent on input:

```py
ScoreBaseType = Union[bool, int, float]
ScoreTypeVar = TypeVar('ScoreTypeVar', bound=ScoreBaseType)

ScoreDictType = Union[ScoreTypeVar, Dict[str, ScoreTypeVar]]


def scoring_func(Iterable[ScoreTypeVar]) -> ScoreDictType:
    ...
```

If you're not doing this based on input values though, you probably want

```py
ScoreBaseType = Union[bool, int, float]
ScoreDictTypes = Union[Dict[str, bool], Dict[str, int], Dict[str, float]]
ScoreComplexType = Union[ScoreBaseType, ScoreDictTypes]
```

Depending on how you are handling the types, you may also be able to use `SupportsInt` or `SupportsFloat` types rather than both `int` and `float`

Edit: (Additional Info Based on the edited OP below)

Since you are typing an ABC with this, it may be sufficient to type the base class using `Dict[str, Any]` and constrain subclasses further.

If it isn't, you are going to have very verbose type definitions, and there isn't much alternative, as mypy currently has [some issues resolving some classes of programmatically generated types](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/2813), even when operating on constants.

mypy also doesn't have support for recursive type aliases at this time ([though there is a potential of support for them being added](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/182#issuecomment-185996450), it's [not currently planned](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/182#issuecomment-199495552)), so for readability, you'd need to define the allowed types for each potential level of nesting, and then collect those into a type representing the full nested structure.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Revised my original post to give a more fleshed out desired usage example. In particular, I have several nested dictionaries (ick). It'd either be `Dict[str, Dict[str, Union[bool, int, float]]` or `Dict[str, Dict[str, Dict[str, Union[bool, int, float]]]`, depending on the subclass.

Comment: I've gone ahead and updated my answer to reflect your edit, but it might be more an answer confirming a lacking feature and how to handle it rather than an easy fix.

Comment: I made another edit... what do you think of the tuple approach (as opposed to triple-nested dictionary)? It seems to pass mypy in a toy example, but I don't want to invest time refactoring a bunch of code only to find a hiccup I didn't think of.

Comment: I don't think I know enough about your code to make specific recommendations around the design. Dictionaries and tuples have different pros and cons, so switching the data type out could result in a change in performance.